# Next.js page not found if route ends with a slash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am currently working on a `next.js` application. The issue i am facing is with `next/link`. Link works well if i am navigating through the application. Every page is rendered properly. The problem shows up when i refresh a page and the URL ends with a slash.

```
http://localhost:3000/about/
```

The above route is showing "Page not found" while the following route will load the page successfully.

```
http://localhost:3000/about
```

I am using `link` as follow:

```
<Link href="/about">
   <a>About</a>
</Link>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: this is how is meant to work.

Comment: @Nico Maybe you are right. But i am asking for a solution for this. I don't want to show up with "Page not found" error.

Comment: You can have a look on this issue : https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/5214

Comment: There are some work around from the issue I put

Comment: Redirect from 404 is not an elegant solution, you should instead pass the proper url (ex. do a regex and remove last /) or if you use express, add custom routes

Comment: @Nico Can you please show me an example that how can use regex?

Comment: `let url = '/home/'; console.log(  url.replace(/\/([^\/]*)$/, '$1')  )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope there should be an easiest way to do that. However you can do this using [custom server](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/custom-server-express). Here is an example:-

```
server.get("/about/", (req, res) => {
  return app.render(req, res, "/about")
})
```

Comment: The op never mentioned that is using / want to use express. also with this solution he should add a route for each page, better use  express path-to-regexp

Comment: Yes there should be an easiest way. This is little bit tricky, though a solution. And Yes we should use regex. That was for single one.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this issue by switching out the  tags for a simple  tag.
Not ideal but at least it prevented the default handling of the trailling slash by nextjs.

```
<a href="/about">About</a>
```

In my case I was directing to a page where I had no control over the url format.